# Strange iOS VoiceOver behavior

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

Some of my testers reports me a strange behavior and I would like to know if anybody else has seen this and a potential fix.

The problem is quite simple. I use ver often `UIAccessibilityTraitDirectInteraction`. Before the user can access to views set such that they need to tap one more time to let VoiceOver activate the direct interaction.

Some users report that in random situation even if you touch the view VO can't allow the direct interaction. The strange thing is that this also happens if the stop/reset the device ando/or exit to the app through the application switch.

I'm sorry if I can't give more details, but we can't find the origin/trigger of this bug/problem.

Has anybody else had a similar situation?

Comment: I assume most of them were on iOS 6 when you asked this question. Any resolution? How is it under iOS 7?

Comment: Unfortunately people having this problem stopped being testers because they needed a full recovery each time from iTunes. Many users experimented this issue with other accessible apps too. IOs7 no longer requires the additional tap to activate custom gestures views, they are already active! Hope this "bug" was solved!